# PHP: Search properly

Tags: php

I have this right now:

```
if(isset($_POST["search"]) && !empty($_POST["search"])) {
    $full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
    $sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sex"]);
    list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $full_name));
    $query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE (firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR lastname LIKE '$lastname') AND sex = '$sex'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array  ($result1)){
        echo $get["firstname"] . " " .$get["lastname"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

This is my search query. Now the form is called "Search for full names". You type in, and then it splits to $firstname , $lastname.

Works great, no problems.

Although if you ONLY enter a user´s LASTNAME, because maybe you dont remember the users firstname, then this code will take it as a firstname, because all before a space is firstname (list() line), and puts it in $firstname and will result nothing, as there's no firstname with that lastname.

How can i solve this? If you search by firstname it works fine, full name too, but not only lastname. Any smart solution?

Comment: Personally, I would refactor the whole thing and use two input fields, one for each name. If a person enters three words, you don't know if the middle word is part of the first name, last name, or a middle name. With the current implementation, you may want to consider adding a limit=2, trimming whitespace, and checking for multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: Where should i trim the white space. i added limit from your answer. And I know this with enters three words, but my site is build up with no middle names and such only first last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the simplest solution:

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $full_name, 2));
if (!$lastname) $lastname = $firstname;
```

Edit: Added a limit to the explode line.

Comment: Hi. I dont understand, if  lastname´s empty then fill it with firstname?

Comment: +1 I reckon this is what I'd do. (Values are OR'd in the WHERE clause)

Comment: What don't you understand? If a person only enters a single value, it could be either a first name or a last name. Thus, you need to search both fields for the same value.

Comment: That was nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can build a series of conditions:

1. Split the input on space
2. For each item in the resulting array, append OR firstname='value' OR lastname='value'

So smith becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (firstname='smith' OR lastname='smith') ....
```

And john smith becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (firstname='john' OR lastname='john' OR firstname='smith' OR lastname='smith') ....
```

If that's not to your liking then you can break out the search terms so you can enter first and last name separately.

Answer (score 1):

Search for both(or more) list items, since names may contain spaces and look for unique results.

```
$arr_name= explode(' ', $full_name);

foreach($arr_name as $name){
 $query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE (firstname LIKE '$name' OR lastname LIKE '$name') AND sex = '$sex'"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_POST["search"])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
    $sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sex"]);
    $query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort
              FROM users
              WHERE (firstname = '$name'
                     OR lastname = '$name'
                     OR CONCAT(firstname, lastname) = '$name'
                     OR CONCAT(lastname, firstname) = '$name')
                    AND sex = '$sex'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo $get["firstname"] . " " . $get["lastname"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

I simply check whether it the search input is the first name, the last name, both first name and last name or both last name and first name.

PS: A nice side affect of this version is that it will find names like `Milhouse van Houten`, too. Your original version (and many of the here proposed ones) couldn't deal with this case. They would look for `Milhouse` and `van`.

PPS: You probably chose a `*_ci` collation for the database. Thus string comparison will be case-insensitive: You don't need to `ucfirst`.